# Can we refer different value to ipfs hash?

Tags: ipfs

I am experimenting with ipfs these days. And one thing I wanna clarify is that in ipfs everything is referenced using a hash ( content hash). But hashes are very long, hard to remember. Is there any way I can refer the content I am retrieving by its name (I know, it can't be refer by its name) or something else.
And how do I refer the content when using ipfs in my application (JS or Go)? Do I store the hash of every content that is put into the application or there is some other mechanisms to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [DNSLinks](https://docs.ipfs.io/guides/concepts/dnslink/), [IPNS](https://docs.ipfs.io/guides/concepts/ipns/).
You can use the DNSLinks to have some more readable names for what you put on IPFS.
For what you parse FROM IPFS, you can index that in your app, with a map between hashes and nice names. 
You can look at the [Github for Javascript](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs#name).